# Solaris 11 ACL issue with copying into acl folder

Tags: acl, zfs

I'm having an issue with ACL inheritance, I have created a folder `/test1` and have set acl's on it. When I copy a file/folder from for example `/tmp/test.txt` to `/test1` it gives the new file both the old permissions and the new acl permissions.

How can I just make it have the new permissions?

I have set aclmode=passthrough and aclinherit=passthrough on the ZFS datasets.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Do both files/dirs have the same permission format? I tested your example on illumos, and /tmp has the old `getfacl`/`setfacl` permissions, incompatible with the new NFSv4 permissions. If I copy the file from another filesystem, it works like you describe that it should (dropping the old ACLs, applying the new ones).

Comment: @user121391 No one is set for example `chmod 755` in `/tmp` and the other is set using `chmod A0=write_attributes...` I am using the cp -r command to copy the files.